# Custom theme: How to call archive-post.php for viewing blog posts

Tags: theme-development, themes

Learning from [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-separate-page-for-blog-posts-in-wordpress/) tutorial, I added a blog page, using the admin panel, to an already running website that has a custom theme made from scratch (by someone else). But the new blog page, didn't show anything other than the website footer in the beginning, so I added a piece of code in the `index.php`, and fixed it... Now when `example.com/blog/` is called, the blog posts are drawn.

I want to follow the common/correct convention, and perhaps have another file like `archive-post.php` do the task. I am not sure how to do that. I read [Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) & [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). I don't Understand if WordPress automatically follows that template hierarchy, or It is just a recommended practice, and I should use [get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/), to make such a hierarchy. If so, is using `get_template_part` the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to rename the `archive.php` as `archive-post.php`. Cause it is default to `post` for `archive.php`. If you have any other post type then use `archive-{post_type}.php` for pointing this template to this post type.

Now come to [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/). It is used for breaking the large code base of the template to single part so it can be managed easily as well as be reused. So it's better to use it. Cause it makes development and code maintain easy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There was no default archive.php in the beginning, and I added the first one. But still only the index.php is called for blog page and blog posts. Do i have to MANUALLY divert the execution path to the archive.php, or is it supposed to happen automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `categoey.php` template as this is effectively what `archive-post.php` would be. The `archive.php` template is used as a template for all post types unless a more specific template can be found.

I highly recommend studying the [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), which is summarised visually as either the [image](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png) or [interactive version](https://wphierarchy.com/).